# Xamarin.iOS: how to determinate the statusbar height in ViewWillTransitionToSize

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, statusbar, screen-rotation, viewwilltransitiontosize

I have have a View containing:

- a `MKMapView`, to display some **items on a map**
- an `UITableView` embedded in a `UIView`, to display the **items in a list**

The user must be able to display the map or the list, by moving a **separator**.

This works well, but **I encounter an issue after the user rotates the screen**: in this case, the list is no longer correctly displayed.

The **list's position** `UIView` is setted by specifying it's top margin constraint: the first time I know the **status bar height** (with `UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarFrame.Height`).

**But after the rotation, I need to recalculate this constraint.** For this, I try to recalculate the constraints in `ViewWillTransitionToSize()`.

My problem is that I don't get the expected value during the call to  `ViewWillTransitionToSize()`: the **"old" value** of `StatusBarFrame.Height` is setted.

I also try to get the **statusbar status** 
 with `UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarHidden` but the problem is the same.

***Is there another way allowing me to get the correct statusbar height during the rotation?***

Comment: Can you provide the sample or some code?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the statusbar status at the wrong place:

```
public override void ViewWillTransitionToSize(CoreGraphics.CGSize toSize, IUIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator coordinator) 
{
    coordinator.AnimateAlongsideTransition((IUIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext obj) => {
        // Define any animations you want to perform (equivilent to willRotateToInterfaceOrientation)
        // StatusBar status and height is not yet updated
    }, (IUIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext obj) => {
        // Completition executed after transistion finishes (equivilent to didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation)
        // StatusBar status and height is well updated
    });

    base.ViewWillTransitionToSize(toSize, coordinator);
}
```

If the test is dont correctly, this works fine.